# Java show fileinputstream without converting to file

Tags: java, file, fileinputstream

I have written a code which opens the File object with the exact application in any os, I was wondering, is it possible to show the inputstream without converting it to a file and saving on localstorage?
Or use the memory ?

Comment: Please try and clarify your question it's very difficult to understand what you've done and what you want

Comment: If you are asking whether it’s possible to use the underlying system to open data from an InputStream as if it’s a file, without copying the InputStream’s data to a file… the answer is no.

Comment: @g00se I want to give the stream to a method which detects the os and opens the file with the exact application in the os which is set to show that extension. without putting stream into a File Object.

Comment: @VGR Thanks. that is the exact thing. is there any way to convert a stream to a file without writing it to hard disk. i want to keep it in memory. so the user won't be able to access it. it is only needed to be loaded once ?

Comment: There's possibly misunderstanding here. `File` in Java is for manipulation of paths mainly and actually has little to do with IO. You should probably read the stream and write it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then call its `toByteArray()` method. Then you would have 'the stream in memory'.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/filefilter/MagicNumberFileFilter.html

Comment: No.  [Desktop.open](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)) requires a real file which is accessible by the system.  I suppose it might be possible to create a ramdisk and write the file there, though I don’t recall offhand how to do that in each operating system.

Comment: I'm interpreting this as magic detection (as in Unix `file`) *prior* to further processing. Also *some* apps will read from stdin so it doesn't *have* always to be present in the file system